# How can I edit Android-grabbed MP4 files in Virtualdub?

Tags: android, mp4, virtualdub, mpeg4

Android's command `adb shell screenrecord x.mp4` [is supposed to](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html#screenrecord) produce MPEG-4 files. VirtualDub is supposed to support MPEG-4 files through the use of the [FFInputDriver plugin](http://thesunstroke.blogspot.no/2014/06/how-to-make-virtualdub-openedit-mkv-mp4.html).

The latter is true because I've been able to open [this sample MP4 video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4) in VirtualDub 1.10.4 with the plugin, so I'm questioning the former. Is Android's adb screenrecord function really producing MPEG-4? Why can't virtualdub read it?

The symptoms when opening the file in VirtualDub is that I only see the first frame. Clicking play does nothing. Attempting to convert it to another format does nothing.

[Here](http://data.nilzorblog.com/div/1.mp4) is a sample video I have dumped from my Nexus 5 phone. It says `.mp4` but I'm unsure.

My OS is Windows 10.0.10240

Comment: I see what looks like an album cover, then what looks like you android home screen ... anyway vlc says http://imgur.com/xK1OERR

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know VLC had that kind of information. I assume you haven't tried it in VirtualDub?

Comment: No. I don't have VirtualDub (whatever that is) installed. I can edit it in AviDemux though.